# read constant from a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA code to read some text files, I would like the file names to be read directly from cells in excel.
I used the following code

> ```
>  Sub ImportFile()
>  Const textFilePath As String = "C:\Desktop\"
>  Const textFileName As String = "File1.txt"
>  Const newTextFileName As String = "NewFile1.txt"
> ```

I want to have something like

> ```
> Sub ImportFile()
> Const textFilePath As String = Range("A2").value
> Const textFileName As String = Range("A3").value
> Const newTextFileName As String = Range("A4").value
> ```

I tried different combinations but it does not seem to like the idea of assigning a constant to a cell value, any work around?

Thanks

P.S I don't know how to write the code in a correct way in this website, I tried to add 4 spaces before the code lines but did not seem to work, any idea why?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't assign a variable value to a constant. The closest you can do is to declare a variable then assign the range value to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can assign a constant from a range because the range value could change during your code execution. I tried your declarations in this bit of code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportFile()
Const textFilePath As String = Range("A2").Value
Const textFileName As String = Range("A3").Value
Const newTextFileName As String = Range("A4").Value
End Sub
```

and on Debug..Compile in the IDE I got this error

[image]

If you change your code to

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportFile()
Dim textFilePath As String
Dim textFileName As String
Dim newTextFileName As String
textFilePath = Range("A2").Value
textFileName = Range("A3").Value
newTextFileName = Range("A4").Value
End Sub
```

You'll find it compiles OK.

Unless you're talking "Universal (physical) constants" like PI,c or G for example, constants rarely are constant. I've found that having a named range, possibly on a hidden sheet, and populating a variable from that named range makes for easier maintenance by users with little no VBA experience. Sure, you need to keep track of those "constants" to maintain them but at least you don't need VBA experience to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in vba since your constant variables might change. However, I think that you want to declare and initialize your path variables once so that later if you decide to change them you can do that in one place in the same row where the variable was initialized. So If I were you I would use something like

```
       Option Explicit

       sub macro()

       Dim FILEPATH As String: FILEPATH = Range("A1").Value

       MsgBox FILEPATH

       end sub
```